# Query to find unique value for the combinations

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Table with two cols ID_COL and VALUE_COL.

```
ID_COL    VALUE_OUT
======    =========
15          10
16          10
16          11
17          10
17          11
17          12
18          10
18          12
19          11
20          11
20          12
21          12
```

this table is populated with some combinations based on our biz rule. Now i want to find the output as follows.

The input from the application is  11,12

we need to search in the above table and need to find the ID_COL.  In this case i need to return the value 20 from ID_COL  ( this is one exact match of 11,12 others having extra values)

It is not two values to match , some times it might be single value also.. if i pass 12 .. i need to return id_col 21

Comment: Will it always be two values input that need to match, or can it be more or less? Will there always be a single matching row to return, or can there be multiples?

Comment: It is not two values to match , some times it might be single value also.. if i pass 12 .. i need to return id_col 21

Comment: Please [edit] your question  and add that information there, because it's relevant to the answer to your question. (It will help those who are trying to answer you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID_COL 
from table 
group by ID_COL 
having 
  count(0) = 2 and
  count(case when VALUE_OUT in (11,12) then 1 end) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly, then you want to find the values in *Id_COL* that satisfies the both the input values passed from application for the *VALUE_OUT*.

You can use the below query for that :

```
    select ID_COL from table where value_out in (11,12);
```

Hope i understood you question correctly.

Hope it helps

Vishad

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id_col
from t
group by id_col
having sum(case when value_out = 11 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value_out = 12 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when value_out not in (11, 12) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The first two clauses in the `having` clause guarantee that each value is present.  The third clause makes sure that there are no other values.

EDIT:

I realize that for your particular case where the values are integers, you could do:

```
having min(value_out) = 11 and max(value_out) = 12;
```

or

```
having min(value_out) = 11 and max(value_out) = 12 and count(distinct value_out) = 2;
```